# Listar subcategorias e posts de categoria/subcategoria atual

Tags: php, wordpress

Em meu arquivo `category.php` tenho um layout onde possuo um menu lateral onde devem ser exibidos as `subcategorias` da `categoria` atual e uma `<section></section>` onde deve ser exibido os posts da atual `categoria` e `subcategoria`, para gerar o menu com as `subcategorias` da `categoria` atual eu fiz:

```
$categories =  get_categories('child_of='.get_the_category()[0]->term_id);

<nav class="panel">
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <a href="<?= get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>" class="panel-block">
            <?= $category->name; ?>
            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-fw"></i></span>
        </a>                
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</nav>
```

Na `section` eu fiz:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&cat='.get_the_category()[0]->term_id); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
        <article class="column is-half">
            <div class="price-label">
                <div class="price-title">
                    <h1 class="title is-6">0001. <?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <h2 class="subtitle is-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis.</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="price-tag has-text-right">
                    <p><span class="size">P</span> <small>R$</small> 21.90</p>
                    <p><span class="size">M</span> <small>R$</small> 25.90</p>
                    <p><span class="size">G</span> <small>R$</small> 35.90</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Eu não consigo fazer com que a `section` pegue sempre os posts da atual pagina sendo ela `categoria` ou `subcategoria`, eu só consigo pegar a `categorial` atual usando `get_the_category()[0]->term_id`, e não sei como pegar os posts da atual `subcategoria`, como posso fazer para que os `posts` seja exibidos de acordo com a atual `categoria` ou `subcategoria`?

Answer (score 0):

Você está reescrevendo a query dentro de `section`, por isso sempre vai mostrar os posts da primeira categoria.

Essa linha é desnecessária e está quebrando o template, pode deletar inteira:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=-1&cat='.get_the_category()[0]->term_id); ?>
```

Quando o template é carregado o WP já sabe qual categoria/subcategoria você quer então a parte `cat=etc` é desnecessária. Pra passar o parâmetro `posts_per_page` use o hook `pre_get_posts` no seu functions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'retira_paginacao' );
function retira_paginacao( $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    } 
}
```

Comment: A propósito: https://naousequeryposts.wordpress.com/

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, quando tento montar o menu gostaria de sempre pegar a categoria `pai` (principal) pois quando acesso as subcategorias do modo que estou escrevendo eu recebo um `array` vazio, estou tentando usar `get_the_category()` mas sempre me retorna um `array` vazio tambem.

Comment: `get_the_category` serve pra buscar categorias associadas a um post específico. Se vc quer saber a categoria do template, use `single_term_title()` para pegar o titulo ou `get_queried_object()` pra pegar o objeto atual da consulta.